# Can a struct implement two traits with conflicting method names in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

Is it possible to implement two traits with conflicting method names in Rust? I know that it gives you a `multiple applicable methods in scope` error, but is there a way to resolve this? For example, some languages handle multiple inheritance by allowing you to explicitly specify which one method should take precedence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [universal function call syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ufcs.html).  The following are all equivalent:

```
let v = 32;
let _ = v.clone();
let _ = Clone::clone(&v);
let _ = <i32 as Clone>::clone(&v);
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name